# Sending a signal from a button to a parent window

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm making an app with PyQt5 that uses a FileDialog to get files from the user and saves the file names in a list. However I also want to be able to remove those entries after they are added, so I created a class that has a name(the file name) and a button. The idea is that when this button is clicked the widget disappears and the file entry is removed from the list. The disappearing part works fine but how to I get the widget to remove the entry form the list? How can i send a signal from one widget inside the window to the main app and tell it to remove the entry from the list?

I know the code is very bad, I'm still very new to PyQt and Python in general so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qw
import sys


class MainWindow(qw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # List of opened files
        self.files = []

        # Main Window layout
        self.layout = qw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.file_display = qw.QStackedWidget()
        self.file_button = qw.QPushButton('Add File')
        self.file_button.clicked.connect(self.add_file)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.file_display)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.file_button)
        self.setCentralWidget(qw.QWidget())
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.layout)

    # Open File Dialog and append file name to list
    def add_file(self):
        file_dialog = qw.QFileDialog()
        self.files.append(file_dialog.getOpenFileName())
        self.update_stack()

    # Create new widget for StackedWidget remove the old one and display the new
    def update_stack(self):
        new_stack_item = qw.QWidget()
        layout = qw.QVBoxLayout()

        for file in self.files:
            layout.addWidget(FileWidget(file[0]))

        new_stack_item.setLayout(layout)

        if len(self.file_display) > 0:
            temp_widget = self.file_display.currentWidget()
            self.file_display.removeWidget(temp_widget)

        self.file_display.addWidget(new_stack_item)


class FileWidget(qw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name):
        # This widget is what is added when a new file is opened
        # it has a file name and a close button
        # my idea is that when the close button is pressed the widget is removed
        # from the window and from the files[] list in the main class
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = qw.QHBoxLayout()

        self.file_name = qw.QLabel(name)
        self.close_button = qw.QPushButton()
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.remove)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.file_name)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.close_button)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def remove(self):
        self.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Just did feel free to ask anything and tell me how bad it is, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove from the list in the `remove` method of the`FileWidget` class.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qw


class FileWidget(qw.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, name, files):                             # + files
        super().__init__()

        self.files = files                                       # +
        self.name = name                                         # +

        self.layout = qw.QHBoxLayout()
        self.file_name = qw.QLabel(name)
        self.close_button = qw.QPushButton("close {}".format(name))
        self.close_button.clicked.connect(self.remove)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.file_name)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.close_button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    def remove(self):
        self.files.pop(self.files.index(self.name))               # <<<-----<
        self.close()


class MainWindow(qw.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # List of opened files
        self.files = []

        # Main Window layout
        self.layout = qw.QVBoxLayout()
        self.file_display = qw.QStackedWidget()
        self.file_button = qw.QPushButton('Add File')
        self.file_button.clicked.connect(self.add_file)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.file_display)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.file_button)
        self.setCentralWidget(qw.QWidget())
        self.centralWidget().setLayout(self.layout)

    # Open File Dialog and append file name to list
    def add_file(self):
        file_name, _ = qw.QFileDialog().getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File') # +
        if file_name:                                                      # +
            self.files.append(file_name)                                   # +
            self.update_stack()

    # Create new widget for StackedWidget remove the old one and display the new
    def update_stack(self):
        new_stack_item = qw.QWidget()
        layout = qw.QVBoxLayout()

        for file in self.files:
            layout.addWidget(FileWidget(file, self.files))                 # + self.files

        new_stack_item.setLayout(layout)
        if len(self.file_display) > 0:
            temp_widget = self.file_display.currentWidget()
            self.file_display.removeWidget(temp_widget)
        self.file_display.addWidget(new_stack_item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = qw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks works fine. Actually found a different solution. I just passed the main window as the parent of the filewidget and the remove function from filewidget calls the remove_file function from the parent with the file_name of the widget.